# SVN and read-only files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to subversion. When I do SVN checkout of a repository I get all files with read-only attribute set. I thought that SVN works differently and leaves files read-write all the time. I tried to remove RO attribute, change the files and commit them, but SVN sets them read-only again.

I'm using 
TortoiseSVN 1.6.5, Build 16974 - 32 Bit , 2009/08/20 08:13:46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't SVN related at all, at least not directly.

I have PushOk installed on my machine because we are using CVS on other projects. And PushOk sets up an "SCC RW Monitor" service that sets RO attribute "for the correct behavior of IDE systems". I turned monitoring SVN files off and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Do the files have the svn:needs-lock property set on them?

Answer (score 1):

I Agree to Roger.

You could try to acquire a Lock on the files you want to modify. This removes the RO attribute until you release the files again. Use **TortoiseSVN → Get Lock...**

To release the lock commit the files or remove manually via TortoiseSVN → Release Lock

Look at chapter  **4.21. Locking** in the TortoiseSVN help